# Typescript module alias path in tests highlighted

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm having a problem with vscode itself. After adding paths for simpler import nested modules I've found that vscode is accepting the imports using newly added aliases `@app` and `@component` within the `src/` directory. Unfortunately it totally ignores those imports within the `test/` folder. The tests are working fine and `jest` doesn't complain about those aliases. But vscode for some reason is showing me middle finger all the time. I've found out that vscode stop marking those imports with red line when I include `test` folder in `tsconfig.json` file. Did you have any similar problem with that? What's the best approach to deal with this issue?

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "paths": {
          "*": ["*"],
          "@app/*": [ "./src/*" ],
          "@component/*": [ "./src/components/*" ],
      },
      "sourceMap": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "allowJs": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "outDir": "./build/"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./test/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to better see what the problem is

> tsc --traceResolution | grep @app

if you are using vscode you have to restart it after changing your path alias